# Hide Domain Folder via Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am trying to remove a part of my URL and make an app available on sub-domain level.

Users shall access `mail.example.com`. The mailing app is currently available at `mail.example.com/mail`. How can I proxy user, opening `mail.example.com`, while accessing `mail.example.com/mail` via NGINX?

Following config fails for CCS and other files:

```
server {
    listen          443 ssl http2;
    server_name     mail.example.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass      https://1.2.3.4/mail$request_uri;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_redirect      off;
    }
}
```